# Open XSD file in browser without downloading

Tags: xsd, jboss-eap-7

I have a XSD file deployed in my localhost thru JBOSS EAP 7.0. The problem I have is everytime I open any XSD files in the browser (Edge & Chrome), it is automatically downloading. It should open in the browser like this: [correct view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ik5Jq.png)

Does anyone experience the same? I tried researching extensively but I didn't find any concrete answers. Is this a configuration issue?

Comment: What is the MIME type/HTTP Content-Type that server sends for the .xsd files?

Comment: Where can I see that? I don't have mime-mapping in standalone.xml..

Comment: I would try to use F12 to open the browser's development console which has a tab for network request that shows HTTP headers of requests and responses; try to access your XSD with the browser and check headers the servers sends to the browser. As for changing it for your platform, sorry, I am not familiar with JBoss, I have only seen the question because of the XSD tag.